# Sports Psychology

Tags: discussion, scope

This [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/how-can-i-improve-my-smashes-in-table-tennis/) indirectly addresses an interesting topic...sports psychology.

I understand we haven't had any questions pertaining to this, but how feasible would questions on sports psychology be in regards to our scope? Would such a question be better served elsewhere?

Not asking for a decision, but more of how we, as a community, would approach it. Although it may be [subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), I see excellent research content potential with such a topic...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how or why it would fit better in Skeptics.SE as it's about a particular drill/exercise/technique of table tennis.

I do see the point in raising this meta question though, since we have had issues arguing back and forth on what fits in our scope and what doesn't.

Much like yourself I see great potential in this type of questions (perhaps I am a bit biased :)) and I believe that the scope of Sports.SE should cover it.

Comment: I used your question as an example, but sports psychology is currently an untapped topic on this site.

Comment: No I did not argue against the sports psychology logic, just didn't see how Skeptics.SE came into the picture.